# SwiftUI: Quiz, Toggle categories on/off and filter questions based on category status

Tags: swiftui

I'm building a quiz app where the user should be able to select which categories they want to have, and then I'd like to filter the questions based on whether the category isActive.

I figure solving both would be too much for one post maybe, so I'm focusing on toggling the categories. I have tried creating a updateCategory function in my ViewModel but I can only tap on the first category. If I tap on any other category, only the first one gets updated (changes name and icon). Anyone that can point me in the right direction?

Here's my CategoryModel:

```
struct CategoryModel: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
    var id: String
    var icon: String
    var name: String
    var isActive: Bool
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, icon, name, isActive
    }

}
```

And here's my QuestionModel:

```
struct QuestionModel: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var question: String
    var category: String
    var answer: Int
    var options: [String]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, question, category, answer, options
    }
    
    // Match the answer index with the correct option
    func theAnswer() -> String {
        return (answer >= 0 && answer < options.count) ? options[answer] : ""
    }
}
```

And here's a part of my GameModel:

```
struct Game {
    // Get questions from JSON file
    static var getQuestions: [QuestionModel] = Bundle.main.decode("questions.json")
    // Shuffled questions
    let questions = getQuestions.shuffled()
    
    // Get categories
    var categories: [CategoryModel] = [
        CategoryModel(id: "", icon: "music.quarternote.3", name: "Musik", isActive: true),
        CategoryModel(id: "", icon: "hourglass.bottomhalf.filled", name: "Historia", isActive: false),
        CategoryModel(id: "", icon: "tv.fill", name: "Film & TV", isActive: true),
        CategoryModel(id: "", icon: "pawprint.fill", name: "Natur & Vetenskap", isActive: true),
        CategoryModel(id: "", icon: "globe.europe.africa.fill", name: "Geografi", isActive: true),
        CategoryModel(id: "", icon: "sportscourt.fill", name: "Sport", isActive: true)
    ]
}
```

Here's part of my ViewModel:

```
class GameVM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var game = Game()
    
    //MARK: - Category logic
    var categories: [CategoryModel] {
        game.categories
    }
    
    func updateCategory(category: CategoryModel) {
        if let index = categories.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == category.id }) {
            game.categories[index] = category.updateCompletion()
        }
    }
    
    var categoryIndices: Range<Int> {
        game.categories.indices
    }
}
```

Here's my CategoryListView where I display the categories:

```
struct CategoryListView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = GameVM()
    var columns: [GridItem] = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 8), count: 2)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 8) {
                ForEach(viewModel.categories, id: \.self) { category in
                    CategoryCardView(icon: category.icon, name: category.name, isActive: category.isActive)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 120)
                    .background(
                        category.isActive == true ? Color(UIColor.systemGray6) : Color(UIColor.black)
                    )
                    .cornerRadius(24)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation(.spring()) {
                            viewModel.updateCategory(category: category)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .navigationTitle("Choose Categories")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First part

You are initialising each category with the same id `""`,

```swift
     var categories: [CategoryModel] = [
        CategoryModel(id: "", icon: "music.quarternote.3", name: "Musik", isActive: true),
        CategoryModel(id: "", icon: "hourglass.bottomhalf.filled", name: "Historia", isActive: false),
        CategoryModel(id: "", icon: "tv.fill", name: "Film & TV", isActive: true),
        CategoryModel(id: "", icon: "pawprint.fill", name: "Natur & Vetenskap", isActive: true),
        CategoryModel(id: "", icon: "globe.europe.africa.fill", name: "Geografi", isActive: true),
        CategoryModel(id: "", icon: "sportscourt.fill", name: "Sport", isActive: true)
    ]
```

causing this to return index `0` every time.

```
    if let index = categories.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == category.id }) {
```

Best fix would be to initialise `id` in `CategoryModel` like you have in `QuestionModel`

```swift
struct CategoryModel: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var icon: String
    var name: String
    var isActive: Bool
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, icon, name, isActive
    }

}
```

## Second part

One way of achieving this is to create a `filteredQuestions` variable inside `GameVM` like this

```swift
    var filteredQuestions: [QuestionModel] {
        let filteredCategoryNames = categories
            .filter(\.isActive) // filters for the active categories
            .map(\.name) // turns it into an array containing the name of each category

        return questions.filter { question in
           filteredCategoryNames.contains(question.category)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Initializing the Id did the trick, thank you! Now I need to figure out how to fetch questions based on filteredCategories since they're not connected right now. Is there a way to check if question.category (String) == category.name (String) and if category.name isActive or something like that?

Comment: Yeah, I'll add something to the answer